# psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "airgoLocator_translationexception" already exists

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration, psycopg2

I am experiencing the error using `psycopg2` module:

> psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "airgoLocator_translationexception" already exists

I have returned the migrations back, to a point where I am sure that everything worked

- `python manage.py migrate app 0058`
- `python manage.py migrate app`
- `python manage.py makemigrations`

I have also tried to do

- `python manage.py migrate --fake app`
- `python manage.py migrate`
- `python manage.py makemigrations`

But I have not been lucky. I have the backend in a gitlab image that I lift from a docker, therefore the backend restarts all the time with this error. Therefore I have to make these changes in the migrations and generate a new image, every time I try to test a solution. The database is a postgres that is in another container.

[image: Terminal output]

Comment: Can you share what is in migration  0058?

Comment: @Matias Cocciolo Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Yes, Entering postgres container and changing migrations by hand with insert and delete in django_migrations table